# Having trouble with trigonometry trying to give direction to ball

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Oh God , guys I’m sorry to be bothering again,  I never imagined that start coding AS3 would be this hard (was easier at the very beginning but my mind is blocked now), I’m still unable to make the ball follow the mouse at the speed and angle desired, I took jett’s example but probably I’m not implementing it right, here is the code ; I’ll be explaining what I’ trying to accomplish

```
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
// here I added a custom cursor to my mouse (it’s an aim in png format)
var cursor:MovieClip;
function initializeGame():void
{
cursor = new Cursor();
addChild(cursor);
cursor.enabled = false;
Mouse.hide();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCursor);
```

}

```
function dragCursor(event:MouseEvent):void
{
cursor.x = this.mouseX;
cursor.y = this.mouseY;
}

initializeGame();
var mouse=this.Mouse;

// here I want to make the player  (called kicker) to kick the ball
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);

function kick(evt:Event){

kicker_mc.play(); // here I animate the kicker movieClip

this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, moveBall);// this is the function that will move     the ball towards the goal

}

//And here unsuccessfully trying to make the ball start moving to the cursor position,     (currently when I kick the ball it appears at the right upper corner of the swf, exactly where the cursor appears when movie is tested

var speed:Number;
var angle:Number;
speed=200;
angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y-bola.y, mouse.x-bola.x);

function moveBall (event:Event){

ball.x += Math.cos (angle) * speed;
ball.y += Math.sin (angle) * speed;


}
```

Once again I’ll really appreciate your guidance guys

### **OLD QUESTION**

I Started creating a Soccer Penalty Shootout game with AS3 but I’m having trouble giving speed and direction  to the ball once it is kicked, I was unable to make the player kick the ball (yes I’m not a developer but I’ve been trying hard to complete the game ) so I managed to put a delay on a function which allows me to move the ball to the goal 3.5 seconds later while the animation of the player simulates the kick, this is the code:

```
kick_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);

function kick(evt:Event)
{
    kicker_mc.play();

    new delayedFunctionCall (myFunctionToStartLater, 350);

    function myFunctionToStartLater():void
    {    
        ballkicked();
    }
}

function ballKicked(event:Event)
{
    ball_mc.y=180;
}
```

Now check that I’m only moving the ball to a different position but I want to throw it to the goalkeeper in the function ballkicked();  here’s is where I want to give real movement to the ball so the shoot can be a goal,  I know I would need to use some trigonometry to give direction and speed but trigonometry seems to be very complicated, I was following a tutorial but  I was only able to prepare some variables and parameteres but then I got lost:

```
var xSpeed:Number;
var ySpeed:Number;
var angle:Number;
var speed:Number;
```

This should go on the function:

```
angle = this.rotation / 180 * Math.PI;
xSpeed = Math.cos(angle) * speed;
ySpeed = Math.sin(angle) * speed;
```

I will really appreciate your patience and help with this, I really want to learn how to do things and I don’t want to give up.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The atan2 function will give you the angle to "throw" ball. To do this, you will need two position vectors, for example we'll use the mouse position to ball position.

```
angle = atan2(mouse.y-ball.y, mouse.x-ball.x)
```

notice that y coords are used first. This will give you a number from which you can progress the ball forward with:

```
ball.x += cos(angle)*speed
ball.y += sin(angle)*speed
```

this will make the ball move toward where the mouse is. However you will need to take into account gravity by curving the angles closer to ground. When the ground is hit you can simply decrease speed and flip the y of vector.

**You may find using an additional acceleration vector useful. **
With this you could set the acceleration vector similarly to what I showed above:

```
//same as above
ball.accx += cos(angle)*speed
ball.accy += sin(angle)*speed
```

initially. Then just add this vector to your pos vector on every frame. After your initial frame you will want to provide some sort of damping and gravity- this is up to you how you would like to implement.

An alternative way to compute this is to use a sine wave to illustrate the path. You can see an example here: [sinewave](http://processing.org/learning/basics/sinewave.html), this is easier initially but you will need to learn the concepts of vectors to deal with collisions such as what I showed above.

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thanks a lot man, I've been dealing with this all day and I was about to quit believe me, thanks God for Stackoverflow. I really appreciate it friend, now I have hope again.

Comment: I think my delay function is causing some troubles to this option, I think I need to get rid of it but cannot imagine the way to make the player kick the ball after the kick animation is finished, a hitTest on last frame inside Kicker's movieClip?  any idea will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd personally use circle distance as an easy measurement. You can also derive angle extremely easily with this as well. Check to see if the distance between ball and foot is less than some number and if so you have a collision.

Comment: Thanks a lot jett, that makes a lot of sense, will try it right away. Really appreciated pal!