# Not making it with AS3 and trigonometry, need to get the ball moving to goal

Tags: actionscript-3, physics, trigonometry

Oh God , guys I’m sorry to be bothering again, I never imagined that start coding AS3 would be this hard (was easier at the very beginning but my mind is blocked now), as I explained in my 1st post here [Having trouble with trigonometry trying to give direction to ball](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11897882/1567903) , I want to make the ball move to the mouse position once the ball once it is kicked, I mean throw the ball to the spot where the cursor is located at  the speed and angle desired, I took jett’s example but probably I’m not implementing it right, here is the code :

```
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
// here I added a custom cursor to my mouse (it’s an aim in png format)
var cursor:MovieClip;
function initializeGame():void
{
cursor = new Cursor();
addChild(cursor);
cursor.enabled = false;
Mouse.hide();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCursor);
}
function dragCursor(event:MouseEvent):void
{
cursor.x = this.mouseX;
cursor.y = this.mouseY;
}

initializeGame();
var mouse=this.Mouse;

// here I want to make the player  (called kicker) to kick the ball
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);

function kick(evt:Event){

kicker_mc.play(); // here I animate the kicker movieClip

this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, moveBall);// this is the function that will move     the ball towards the goal

}

//And here unsuccessfully trying to make the ball start moving to the cursor position,     (currently when I kick the ball it appears at the right upper corner of the swf, exactly where the cursor appears when movie is tested

var speed:Number;
var angle:Number;
speed=200;
angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y-bola.y, mouse.x-bola.x);

function moveBall (event:Event){

ball.x += Math.cos (angle) * speed;
ball.y += Math.sin (angle) * speed;
}
```

I will always be in debt if somebody give a hand making the ball move, later on I will start with the physics but now my mind is exhausted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you the ball does not move?

`this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, moveBall);`

convert to

`this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);`

Comment: Thanks bitmabdata.com, got this error after the change: ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on penales_fla::MainTimeline/moveBall(). Expected 0, got 1.

Comment: I don't understand. what the problem my hint. because when i tested no problem. I would like you to be glad to help. are you give a your full-code link?

Comment: Thanks bitmabdata.com!!! man you are great pal, this is the file my friend, I was able to make some movement now after making some changes[link]https://rapidshare.com/files/1311098536/penalty.fla but you see the ball is moving really bad :(

Comment: sorry i'm so late. I was traffic at work ... here is correct code. check out, and accepted please. some little modified, so you must look at inner bola, pateador_mc, cursor.http://www.datafilehost.com/download-e84a3999.html

Comment: Greeeeeaaat!!! Thank very much bitmapdata.com, it is working perfectly, I really appreciate your help my friend for your help, now I'm more than sure that Stackoverflow is full of friendly and awesome people! Have a great day pal!

Comment: I am so pleased. ^ ^ Do you have any questions. If I here i will be happy to help. And My Friends, `Please accepted my answer. clicked V Button!`